# More Hadiths on Shaking Hands

Tags: hadith, authenticity

There are two hadiths regarding shaking hands that I recently encountered. I would like to know the sources and authenticity of these hadiths.

> The first hadith is regarding Abu-Bakr shaking hands with an old woman during his caliphate.
>
> The second hadith is regarding Ibrahim An-Nakhi shaking hands with women.

JazakAllah

Comment: The caliphat of abu Bakr and the time of Ibrahim an-Nakhai (tabi'y who didn't meet the rashidi caliphs) is after the prophet () so referring to any narration about them as hadith is strictly speaking wrong it is more something like a khabar or athar. And some madhhabs won't accept these narrations as a source of jurisprudence.

Comment: Shaking hands with old women is considered permissible by some of the madhabs, although the report about Abu Bakr is suspect, [Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/21183/shaking-hands-with-a-non-mahram-woman) cites Zayla'i and Ibn Hajar on it.

Comment: The second one needs more elaboration. What is likely reported from Ibrahim al-Nakha'i (in e.g. [Musannaf Abdul Razzaq](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32856/10650) ) is restricted to shaking hands with a cloth partition, not shaking hands with women in general.

Comment: @UmH Thank you very much. Do you mind roughly translating the hadith that you posted from Musannaf Abdul Razzaq? Also, is it authentic? Thank you.

Comment: It says that when the Prophet held or shook hands with women there used to be a cloth on his hand. This is narrated under the chapter on taking oath of allegiance from women alongwith other ahadith that the Prophet only took the oath orally and said that he does not hold than hands of women. It is mursal as Ibrahim does not attribute it to a Sahabi and himself did not meet the Prophet, and the evidence contrary to it is stronger such as the [hadith of Ayesha](http://sunnah.com/muslim/33/131) and analogy with the prohibition of looking from the Quran.